# Encrypt columns data in postgresql database with pgcrypto

Tags: postgresql, security, encryption, gnupg, pgcrypto

I have a postgres database with some tables  having columns containing some sensitive data, i used **PGCRYPTO** extension  (pgp_pub_encrypt/pgp_pub_decrypt) to encrypt and **gpg** to generate public and private key pairs.

I have two questions :

- Where should i **store** this pair of keys knowing that i should use the same generated private key to decrypt a column ( i tried putting it in postgresql.conf file and that's not working)
- Can we generate key pairs for each session to make the system more secure?

Answer (score 2):

The public key can be stored anywhere. You could store it in the database.

The private key belongs to your application. It should be stored on the application server, so that the application can supply it to decrypt the data in the database.

Comment: Thank's for your answer but i'm wondering how to store KEK and DEK keys and how to make a transparent data encryption alike solution to modify keys through time